# I need to find a function in order to satisfy $f(f^{−1}(W))≠W.$

Tags: functions

For an introductory abstract math course, I have to come up with some examples that satisfy the above property.

For a function $f: A \to B$, with $W \subseteq B$, I need to choose $A, B, W$ and the function in order to satisfy $f(f^{-1}(W)) \not= W$.

I have tried several functions, including $|x|, x^2, $ and a few piece-wise functions, but I cannot find one that satisfies this property. Does anyone have any tips for this?

Answer (score 3):

Guide:

Try to let $W$ be something that is bigger than its range.

Answer (score 2):

Take $A = B= \mathbb{N}$, $W = \{1,2\}$ and constant function $f(x)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Just pick any $b\in B$ which is not in the image $f(A)$ of $f$. Then $f^{-1}(b)=\varnothing$, so no set $W$ containing $b$ can be mapped back onto itself since $b$ will always be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be defined by $f(x)=x^2$.

Let $W=\Bbb R - \{-1\}$.

Note that $A=B=\Bbb R$ and $W=\Bbb R - \{-1\} \subseteq \Bbb R=B$ as you require.

Then $f(f^{-1}(W))=f(\Bbb R)=[0,\infty)\neq W.$

Comment: I don't really understand this--is it possible for $W$ to contain elements that have no equivalent in $f^{-1}(W)$? For example, $-2$ is an element of  $W$, but you can't take $f^{-1}(-2)$.

Comment: @jeanquilt Yes, It is possible to pick those elements. $f^{-1}(-2)=\emptyset .$

Comment: Every element in the co-domain need not have a pre-image in the domain. Here $-1$ does not have any pre-image under $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the smallest possible example:

Let $A=\emptyset$, $B=W=\{\emptyset\}$, $f$ the inclusion map.

Answer (score 1):

Take f to be non surjective on W.